# Textbox Nodes Won't Appear In Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, venn-diagrams

I am trying to create a simple venn diagram with the labels a,b,c with a U in the right hand corner of the box like this picture:
[image]

I have created the venn diagram the way I wanted to, but I can't create node labels that appear like in the image. Here is what I've made and the source code that I've been using. I've been playing around with different colors and I still can't see it.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=5]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{textbox}=[draw=black, fill=black, thick, rectangle]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, blend group=screen]
  \fill[lightgray] ( 270:.7) circle (1) node [textbox] {\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth} $\boldmath{c}$\end{minipage}};
  \fill[gray] (180:.5) circle (1);
  \fill[darkgray] (0:.5) circle (1);
  \draw[ultra thick, fill=black!100!] ([shift={(-0.1,-0.1)}]current bounding box.south west) rectangle ([shift={(0.1,0.1)}]current bounding box.north east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `blend group` inside a scope. Instead of `screen`, `multiply` is more suited for your case. Further, I have changed the unit vectors instead of `scale`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={draw,very thick,fill=gray!10},
         textbox/.style = {draw, fill=white, thick,text=black}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=4cm,y=4cm,show background rectangle]
 \begin{scope}[blend group=multiply]
  \fill[gray] ( 270:.7) circle (1);
  \fill[gray!30] (180:.5) circle (1);
  \fill[gray!60] (0:.5) circle (1);
 \end{scope}
 \node [textbox] at(270:6cm) {$C$};
 \node [textbox] at(135:4cm) {$B$};
 \node [textbox] at(45:4cm) {$A$};
  \node[textbox] at (current bounding box.north west) {$U$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]